# Curved Menu Responsive possible?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, responsive

a client wants his old menu in his website re-design I should make for him. It looks like this:

[Curved Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfFSB.png)

I tried some code with svg etc but I didn't get it to work.

Is it even possible to make a navigation/menu like this responsive?

Maybe you can help me out with a little hint or something. Would be glad about it!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow. Please provide us with [mcve] so that we can help you. Please show us the code you wrote, because otherwise we can't help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could use the SVG. Then, you could set its `z-index` higher, this way you will bring it to front in page. The menu will have a `z-index` lower than the SVG. Each item of menu will have a `transform: translateY()` moving it up. So you will position each of them differently. Lastly, you will modify the `height` of each item in order to compensate the `transform` displacement.

Like this:

```
.item1 {
  transform: translate(-20px);
  height: 100px;
}
.item2 {
  transform: translate(-40px);
  height: 120px;
}
.item3 {
  transform: translate(-60px);
  height: 140px;
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a ton to you!! helped me a lot. To get the menu to the right would you also use "float: right;"? :-)

Comment: No problem. I'm glad it worked. I'd rather not use `float`. I prefer `flexbox`. You can set `display: flex` to the parent element of menu items. (one effect at first will be that all the items inside will stay in a row). With `flex` "enabled", you can set in this same parent element `justify-content: flex-end` (imagine it's something like "position its content to the right"). It solves the problem, then you can position better with other properties. I strongly suggest you to learn `flexbox`. It's worth it and the browser compatibility is very high.